# Verification link not activating account

Tags: php, mysql

So I've sent a link after registration to Verify an account, the link contains the users email address and a 32 character code for example:

```
                $to      = $email;
                $subject = 'Signup | Verification';
                $message = '

                Thanks for signing up!
                Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials after you have activated your account by pressing the url below.

                ------------------------
                Username: '.$username.'
                Password: '.$password.'
                ------------------------

                Please click this link to activate your account:
                localhost:8888/website/verify.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'
                '; 

                $headers = 'From:myemail@email.com' . "\r\n"; 
                mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

That all seems to work fine I'm receiving the email with a link like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/website/verify.php?email=myemail@email.com&hash=fe646d38bc2145ca6c3cf77d52820cd0
```

The problem comes when I follow the link and try to activate the account. It takes me to Verify.php fine but I keep getting Invalid Approach and I'm unable to set Validation to 1.

```
    <?php include "includes/base.php"; ?>

    <?php

        if(isset($_GET['Email']) && !empty($_GET['Email']) AND isset($_GET['Hash']) && !empty($_GET['Hash'])){
            $email = mysql_escape_string($_GET['Email']); 
            $hash = mysql_escape_string($_GET['Hash']); 
            $search = mysql_query("SELECT Email, Hash, Validation FROM users WHERE Email = '".$email."' AND Hash = '".$hash."' AND Validation = 0") or die(mysql_error()); 
            $match  = mysql_num_rows($search);


            if($match > 0){
                mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Validation = 1 WHERE Email = '".$email."' AND Hash = '".$hash."' AND Validation = 0") or die(mysql_error());
                echo "Your account has been activated, you can now login";
            }else{
                echo "The url is either invalid or you already have activated your account.";
            }

        }else{
            echo "Invalid approach, please use the link that has been sent to your email.";
        }


    ?>
```

Comment: Your code has issues. SQL Injection issues.

Comment: I know, that's next on my list to sort out. Thanks

Comment: Your method has issues, too. NEVER send passwords (except one-time passwords, like your hash) via mail! Why do you even know the password in the first place? You should (or better have to) immediately create a salted hash from the provided password, store this one and forget the clear-text password as soon as possible (wipe it from memory, do not log or store anything). Other things: does your hash contain a secret? Did you use a secure algorithm for it? Does your activation link have a timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) this code is unsecure as it has SQL injection problem. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)
Please keep in mind that **mysql_*** functions are no longer supported and they are [depriated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799)

2) Regarding your code I found that your GET request has 'email' and 'hash' all lowercase, but in PHP code you use $_GET['Email'] and $_GET['Hash'].
You need to change this:

```
 if(isset($_GET['Email']) && !empty($_GET['Email']) AND isset($_GET['Hash']) && !empty($_GET['Hash'])){
            $email = mysql_escape_string($_GET['Email']); 
            $hash = mysql_escape_string($_GET['Hash']);
```

To this

```
 if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['eash']) && !empty($_GET['eash'])){
            $email = mysql_escape_string($_GET['email']); 
            $hash = mysql_escape_string($_GET['eash']);
```

or change your GET request to the next one:

```
http://localhost:8888/website/verify.php?Email=myemail@email.com&Hash=fe646d38bc2145ca6c3cf77d52820cd0
```

Comment: Cheers thats it, I should probably go spend a bit of time on SQL injection issues and the whole mysql_* situation, seems I get that said in a few of my questions.

Comment: @MarkBerry: you might want to read this one: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

Change `Hash` to `hash` & `Email` to `email`. (Capitalized, but not in link that you send)

Also, your code is prone to sql injection attack as you are directly using the values in the url to query your database. Please use `mysql_real_escape_string` and perform some sanity checks before making the query.

Answer (score 0):

there's capitals in the PHP whereas there are none in the link

```
$_GET['Email']

verify.php?email=myemail@email.com
```